# Not able to register through frontend. Keeps saying Bad Request

Tags: python, reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a basic authentication website using DJANGO and REACT. But there seems to be a problem in communication between frontend and backend. I have built a Rest API using DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK and authentication using KNOX whose code is as follows:

```
# api.py

from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .serializers import UserSerializer, RegisterSerializer, LoginSerializer


# Register API
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })


# Login API
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })


# Get User API
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

```
# serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


# User serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')


# Register serializer
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            validated_data['username'], 
            validated_data['email'], 
            validated_data['password']
            )
        return user


# Login serializer
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Credentials")
```

I have tried and tested all the REST API urls using the django rest framework and Postman. They work fine. Here is my frontend code:

```
// Register.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Register extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            email:'',
            password:'',
            username:''
        }
    }
    onNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({username:event.target.value})
    }
    onEmailChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({email:event.target.value})
    }
    onPasswordChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({password:event.target.value})
    }
    onSubmitSignin = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api1/auth/register',{
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                name: this.state.username
            })
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(user=>{
            if(user.id){
                this.props.loadUser(user);
                this.props.onRouteChange('home');
            }
        })
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <article className="br3 ba b--black-10 mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-25-l mw6 center shadow-5">
                <main className="pa4 black-80">
                    <div className="measure">
                        <fieldset id="sign_up" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
                            <legend className="f1 fw6 ph0 mh0">Register</legend>
                            <div className="mt3">
                                <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                                <input className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" type="email" name="name"  
                                id="name"
                                onChange={this.onNameChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="mt3">
                                <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="email-address">Email</label>
                                <input className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" type="email" name="email-address"  id="email-address" 
                                onChange={this.onEmailChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="mv3">
                                <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input className="b pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" type="password" name="password"  id="password" 
                                onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div className="">
                            <input onClick={this.onSubmitSignin} className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib" type="submit" value="Register" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </article>    
        );
    }
    
}

export default Register;
```

Now, everytime I click on the `Register` button, there is no response from the site and on the terminal it shows:

```
Bad Request: /api1/auth/register
"POST /api1/auth/register HTTP/1.1" 400 40
```

I have searched alot related to this error but not able to find any solution.

Comment: are you expecting anything to get executed with you click on legend tag having register?

Comment: @hafizali Yep, it should register and store the user credentials and proceed with my main page. But it's not.

Comment: You aren’t triggering any event clicking on there, correct me if m wrong

Comment: I am linking this with my App.js. And frankly, I am not known with react, I am just trying to integrate frontend with backend. If u could please suggest me the changes.

Comment: @hafizali should I provide u with the app.js code?

Comment: you need to probably debug and breakdown all you want to do into pieces.

e.g 
1. click on register should log in the console.
2. should make a call to backend
3. find out what is breaking.
4. from your python trace i can see that its executing api with post request

Comment: @hafizali I got the 3 points and will try to execute them. I cant understand the 4th point, the POST request is made as it should be right?

Comment: read about post request, its generally done to send some data to the backend so as to update something in the database. in your backend i am not sure you have correctly created register api because in the logs its saying that its a bad request. i am not a python dev so i am not sure how have you created register api on the backend

Comment: @hafizali I have tested the rest api from postman and django rest framework so that works fine. Still I will recheck that. Last question, do u sense any bug or problem in the fronted?

Comment: i don't think so frontend has issues, i have added your code to the link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-swartz-qrs6w?file=/src/Register.jsx

1. my next idea would be to try catch the fetch request in ononSubmitSignin and see what error do you get. worth checking network logs too.

Comment: @hafizali ok got it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The `bad request` means that probably there is something wrong with data send to the server.

What you are sending:

```
onSubmitSignin = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api1/auth/register',{
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                name: this.state.username
            })
        })
```

So your `POST` data has `email, password, name`. In the serializer you have:

```py
user = User.objects.create_user(
            validated_data['username'], 
            validated_data['email'], 
            validated_data['password']
            )
```

So it looks that `username` is missing. Please try to send data in React:

```
onSubmitSignin = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api1/auth/register',{
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                username: this.state.username
            })
        })
```